# How can I list all values stored in a JS array using a button click?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to teach myself JavaScript and was wondering if it was possible to feed values into an array, then have those values listed out inside an HTML element, upon an on-click event?

This is what I'm trying currently :

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form onsubmit="storeItems()">
                Enter value :
                <input type="text" id="box">
                <br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <br/><br/>
                <button type="button" onclick="listItems()" id="show">Show stored values</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>

<div id="showbox"></div>
```

```js
   var items = [];

   function storeItems() {
       valueBox = document.getElementById('box').value;
       items.push(valueBox);
       return false;
   }

   function listItems() {
       var x;
       for (x of items) {
           document.write(x + "<br>");
       }
   }
</script>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you :)

Comment: Add return to your onsubmit: `onsubmit="return storeItems(event)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form>
                Enter value :
                <input type="text" id="box">
                <br/><br/>
                <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="storeItems()">
                <br/><br/>
                <button type="button" onclick="listItems()" id="show">Show stored values</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>

<div id="showbox"></div>

<script>
    var items = [];

    function storeItems() {
        valueBox = document.getElementById('box').value;
        items.push(valueBox);
        document.getElementById('box').value="";
        return true;
    }

    function listItems() {
        var x;
        for (x of items) {
            document.write(x + "<br>");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function on click of the click of the button not on the submission of the form

```js
var items = [];

function storeItems() {
  valueBox = document.getElementById('box').value;
  items.push(valueBox);
  return false;
}

function listItems() {
  var x;
  for (x of items) {
    document.write(x + "<br>");
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        Enter value :
        <input type="text" id="box">
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="storeItems()">
        <br/><br/>
        <button type="button" onclick="listItems()" id="show">Show stored values</button>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="showbox"></div>
```